# WPF auto expand then error not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemscontrol, expand

```
I have some problem in wpf application.

In XAML:   

     <Expander Header="SomeHeader" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderStyle}" IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=Errors, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, Path=IsExpanded}"  >
                <RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource RichTextBoxStyle}" Foreground="Red" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ErrorTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
            </Expander>    
In my ViewModelClass:   

       private List<string> errors;
       public List<string> Errors
       {
            get { return errors; }
            set
            {
                errors = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Errors");
            }
       }
```

In constructor:

```
       public MainWindowViewModel()
       {    
           if (IsInDesignMode) return;    
           Errors = new List<string>();    
       }
```

In test method:

```
       private void TestExcute()
       {
           Errors = "Some error";    
       }
```

In this situation error message not displayed in wpf window. But if I change code in constructor to next:

```
      public MainWindowViewModel()
      {    
           if (IsInDesignMode) return;    
           Errors = new List<string>{"errorMessage1", "errorMessage2"};    
      }
```

Displayed:

errorMessage1

errorMessage2

What is the reason ?

I have new question. In this wpf application I also used Expander control. How create auto expand open, then Errors.count > 0?

I create converter :

public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            LoadFile loadFile = (LoadFile)value;

```
        if (loadingFile.ExcelErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

LoadFile is a class where declared Errors property.

Answer (score 2):

I think you made an error in your `TestExcute` while writing question did you mean to write `Errors.Add("some error")`?

If so then your `ItemsControl` wont react to change because there is no change on property `Errors` - setter is not invoked.

Change your `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>` this class notifies that its content has change and UI will react to that.

Comment: Rafal, Thank you very mutch, I think also